# JasperServer Ignores Always Prompt

Tags: jasperserver

Backstory:
I just upgraded our JasperServer to 7.8.0. All of our reports have the Always prompt checkbox checked under input controls.

In the old version (5.something) the reports are prompting in page like they are supposed to. Meaning that when a report is loaded the user has to give parameters and click the apply button.

The new server loads the report first. Sometimes when using default values our reports will be hundreds of pages and take forever if they ever do load. Just to have the wrong information and give the user a prompt for parameters. I have set the Display mode to every possible option as well as checking and unchecking Always prompt.

Has anyone else had an issue with 7.8.0 ignoring Always prompt?
How can I make it so that the report will prompt first?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue with basic new report? (It can be an issue with importing reports). You can also check the list of known issues (for example, JRS 7.9.0 has a ton of bugs): [Known Issues](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-release-notes/v780/known-issues)

Comment: Let me look. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Even in a new report it is running before clicking apply.

Comment: It does not work even for mandatory input controls, right?

Comment: Correct. When giving mandatory input controls it throws an error. HTML response error code: 500 error ...

Comment: I have the same issue. I know it worked well in the past, and noticed recently that it doesn't anymore. Haven't associated it with the new version (7.8), but looking back it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Solution*

Change display mode of prompt to pop up window from in page or any of the others.

*Not a very good solution but it allows users to use the reports. Unfortunately this is a bug with JRS 7.8 but has beef fixed in pro. Hopefully they will fix this in 7.9.

Comment: Vendor published a [patch v7.8.1](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases#project_releases-old-0) on 2021-Sep-25 for the JasperReports Server version 7.8.0. The issue "JS-59254 Always Prompt Input Control Flag not Working" was closed